# Porting tomcat app to GAE, where to specify resources previously in server.xml?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to move a Java application from tomcat to App Engine. There are some properties specified in server.xml that I'm not sure how to properly specify so that Google will pick them up.

Example:

```
<Resource name="UserTransaction" auth="Container"
          type="javax.transaction.UserTransaction"
          factory="org.objectweb.jotm.UserTransactionFactory"
          jotm.timeout="60"
/>
```

Do I need to change the way the application works, or can these be specified somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App engine does not support JTA. It has a datastore that supports transactions, though. See http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html.

If your Tomcat application uses a transaction manager, I guess it's to be able to use two different databases in the same transaction, or to use JMS. This won't be possible in GAE, which doesn't support JMS, nor relational databases. You'll only have access to the GAE datastore to store your information.